# Support Library Tutorial for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I got severl exceptions while implementing fragments using Support Library like:

- Cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment.
- Fragment xx.yy.FragmentTitles did not create a view.

Can you let me know how can i run Fragment using support Library?

Comment: can you post your code including import statements

Comment: currenlty i fixed the problem. do you still need imports?

Comment: if you have your problem solved then no need to post. But you should post the relevant code if it is not solved

Comment: I shared question to help other people do save their time facing same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a development process:

- you should run define activity which extend ***FragmentActivity*** 
  by importing *android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity*)
- Layout of your activity need to contain some fragments. You can do
  this in several methods, one way is to to add Fragment in you .XML
  layout file.

Sample Layout:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
      android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

please note that you need to define class name in ***android:name*** property.

- You need to implement your fragments by using
  ***android.support.v4.app.Fragment***
- Your fragment need to got a View. You can create this view for ***Fragment*** by overriding ***onCreateView*** method. If you are using ***ListFragment*** (android.support.v4.app.ListFragment) you can ignore this and you can setup your inherited ListView inside ***onCreate*** method at the begging (if required).

---

You can find running tutorials provided by Google here:
[https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Another sample brought here:
http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/12/example-of-using-compatibility-package.html